# ReactiveCommand depending two command on each other

Tags: c#, reactiveui

As a reaction from Shane Neuville I'm changing my question. But yes. It may be more complicated then I first thought it was.

I have a `ReactiveList<ServiceEntryModel> Services;` that will be populated when the view have appeared. With every entry in the list I have used the function called `Services.ItemsAdded.Subscribe()` where the RxCell will be populated with data that at the end of the whole list should be ordered in a specific way. As of now I have have two separate ReactiveCommands.

```
1.ReactiveCommand<Unit, List<ServiceEntryModel>> RefreshServices;

2.ReactiveCommand<Unit, List<ServiceEntryModel>> OrderByCommand;
```

The second command should be called when the whole list is populated from the Services.ItemsAdded.Subscribe method. How can I check/know when every entry is done?

I have tried something with counters and ObservablePropertyHelpers, but without any luck so far.

Here is my ViewModel part that should be relevant

```
Services.ItemsAdded.Subscribe(async entryItem =>
{
    ServiceEntityStatusDto serviceEntityStatus = await GetServiceEntryStatus(entryItem);

    if (serviceEntityStatus != null)
    {
        entryItem.AvailabilityStatus = serviceEntityStatus.AvailabilityStatus;
        entryItem.PerformanceStatus = serviceEntityStatus.PerformanceStatus;
    }
    counterServices++;
    //await OrderServices.Execute(); //TODO infinite loop ?
});
```

The part is commented is a infinite loop, because the Services.ItemsAdded will be continue to be called.

The user can pull to refresh and the first command will be called again, so right when that is done. The seconds should order the whole list again.

Comment: I'm still not quite following. Would it be possible to create a small sample of what you're trying to accomplish? For this "How can I check/know when every entry is done?"  I would ask you the same thing. What are the indicators that it's done? What state does the data reach where you know it's done. You implemented a counter so do you know the number of items? If all you're wanting to do is sort the list then https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/lists/derived-lists.html might be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Is this enough?

```
RefreshServices
    .SelectMany(_ => OrderServices.Execute())
    .Subscribe();
```

Or the InvokeCommand syntax

```
RefreshServices
    .InvokeCommand(OrderServices);
```

The distinction being that with InvokeCommand OrderServices will not execute if it's already executing which might not fit your use case. For example maybe RefreshServices can execute again while OrderServices is still running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I put that?

Comment: You would just place it anywhere after both commands have been instantiated. I included InvokeCommand syntax but I guess I'm curious about your use case a bit. If Order Services is just always called after RefreshServices then why not just make "DoOrderService" part of RefreshServices? Why make it a separate command?  While OrderServices is running can the user issue another RefreshService? Can the user click OrderService without running RefreshService?

Comment: That was my first approach to make DoOrderService a part of the first command. But when the list is being loaded, it will in the background fetch additional data. With 'ItemsAdded' of the ReactiveList. And yes the user can issue another RefreshService while OrderServices is running. although the user cannot click or do anything with OrderService without running RefreshService.

Comment: Hmm apologies but I'm still a bit lost on what the end goal is. For example you say OrderServices should run when Refresh is done but then Refresh can still be ran while Order is running so what does that mean for the new set of data from Refresh? Is the data produced by Refresh unique each time and whatever new data arrives to it needs to make it's way to Order? Maybe edit the original question to further outline the use case? Because it seems like you want a bit more behavior then just executing a second command after a first command finishes.

Comment: I think your right. I thought to lightly about it. I have updated my question. Maybe this makes more sense?